# How can I shape a webview on Android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-activity

I want to padding my textview without disturbing my background image but when I made padding on relative layout it crops my background from all around moreover when I try to padding from textview itcrops my text

here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TesbihMainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backroundimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/tesbihbackround"
         />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#e9ebec"
        android:text=" 385 "
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="52dp"
        android:textColor="#3c677b"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:layout_margin=""` on your textView instead of `android:padding=""`.
This will make a margin with inserted value in TextView to all the directions (Top,Bottom,Left and Right) of the textView

You can also use these if you want a specific margin applied:

```
android:layout_marginLeft=""
android:layout_marginTop=""
android:layout_marginRight=""
android:layout_marginBottom=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Margin on your TextView, instead of Padding.

Padding adds space inside the View.
Margin adds space outside!

For Example:
Padding on TextView will move the content of the TextView away from the borders of the TextView.
Margin on TextView will move the whole TextView away from its parent's borders.